# how do i make a script to generate a gpg backup saver?

Tags: bash, shell-script, cron, backup, gpg

Im making a little backup script that includes the function to encrypt the backup. The script runs automaticly with a cronjob. So the password for gpg is in a File. Its just a textfile. How can i improve the security of the file so no one can see the blank password there?

Greez Nyno

Comment: Which encryption method do you use?

Answer (score 4):

i came across the same problem a while ago.

The easiest solution is: do not not use gpg's symmetric encryption (-c) for backups, which arises the need for a password. Instead use the asymetric (-e -r ) encryption, with pubkey and privkey.

You would then set the key to "trusted ultimately", and encrypt to the public key.

The private key is not on the system (Exported and then deleted from the machine's keyring), but kept somewhere else in a safe place. So no-one can decrypt this backup, except you when needed.